# localhost can access wordpress but 127.0.0.1 cannot

Tags: wordpress

OS :ubuntu
when I enter `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress`,
 
show error:

```
Neither /etc/wordpress/config-127.0.0.1.php nor /etc/wordpress/config-0.0.1.php could be found. 
Ensure one of them exists, is readable by the webserver and contains the right password/username.
```

but `http://localhost/wordpress` can access

I had used command `bash /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql -n wordpress localhost` which may cause this error.And I also want to figure out what that command means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finaly,I figure it out myself.

1. alter siteurl column under wp_options table,set localhost to host machine ip.such as `http://192.168.2.16/wordpress`
2. alter home column under wp_options table,and set localhost to host machine ip,as above.
   (If one don't do 1 and 2,you can not see img )
3. `sudo ln -s /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php /etc/wordpress/config-default.php`
   (this is because at last wp-config.php looks for config-default.php)

then,this problem solved~

Comment: great, thanks man! This allowed me to access my wp website installed as localhost on my laptop from within my LAN using other devices. I was struggling to find out a solution and your procedure worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Wordpress database is probably configured for 'localhost' 
You need to change a couple of table entries to make it work

Comment: bash /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql -n wordpress localhost. I use above command，how can I undo it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the mapping is set to resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1

try:

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/hosts
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the above answer, this did not work, one Debian Jessi 8.1,  because /etc/wordpress/config-default.php does not exist.

However, I did:

ln -s /etc/wordpress/config-dev.php /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php

which got me past this hurdle. However, the next problem is "
As per the above answer, this did not work, one Debian Jessie 8.1,  because /etc/wordpress/config-default.php does not exist.

However, I did:

ln -s /etc/wordpress/config-dev.php /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php

which got me past this hurdle.

However, the next problem is "Error establishing a database connection" which is beyond the scope of this question.